# JQuery osx style modal window content doesnt seem to work

Tags: jquery, macos, modal-dialog

I am developing an application where i am using jquery osx style modal window and inside that i have a telerik date picker and a combo box. When i click on an imaeg the modal window should open up with the datepicker and combo box. So after page load when i click an image the modal window opens up and displays the content. But after closing the window when i again click the image to reopen the window the datepicker and combobox doesnt seem to be working. I am not able to open the date popup as well as combobox. But if i reload the page than it works. Why does this happen? I use firebug but didnt get any solution from it. I want to solve this as soon as possible. Please suggest me any workaround for this.

Thank You.